# Spring Integration - Threaded Outbound Channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Thanks in advance!  I am working on a simple TCP integration where the goal is to have many clients connected to the server and to facilitate asynchronous messages between the client and server.  I have pieced together some code from examples and everything is working as expected except one thing:

When one connection stalls (not disconnects, but does something like drop all packets) all the other connections stop receiving messages until the one recovers.  What should I implement or change in order to allow communication to clients be independent of connection woes with other clients?

Server config is as follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.*;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;

import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;



@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IntegrationConfig.class);

    @Value("${listen.port:8000}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    Relayer relayer;

    @Bean  //for accepting text message from TCP, putty
    public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
        return new ExecutorChannel(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean  //inbound, it is working, I could read the inbound message while debugging
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter in(
            AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return adapter;
    }
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(100);
        return taskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel toTcp() {
        ExecutorChannel directChannel = new ExecutorChannel(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
        relayer.setOutboundChannel(directChannel);
        return directChannel;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler out(
            AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutboundAdp = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        tcpOutboundAdp.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return tcpOutboundAdp;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
    public void handleIncompingMessage(Message<byte[]> stringMsg) {
        String new_message = new String(stringMsg.getPayload());
        new_message = new_message.replaceAll("\r", "");
        new_message = new_message.replaceAll("\n", "");
        relayer.processIncomingMessage((String) stringMsg.getHeaders().get("ip_connectionId"), new_message);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(this.port);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer());
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayLfSerializer());
        return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
    }
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        relayer.newConnection(event.getConnectionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        relayer.deleteConnection(event.getConnectionId());
    }
}
```

This is based on many examples, and again, it all works except when one client lags out.  I have other parts of my app talking to the output channel, should I have an aggregator of some sort in the middle?

Cheers!

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what the problem is that you are describing, but I can't think of anything in the framework where one connection would affect others; perhaps take a thread dump to see what's happening? Perhaps also add your `Relayer` code? Debug logging might help too.

Comment: Hi Gary, super big fan here by the way! :)
All the relayer is doing is sending info received to another application, and there is a point where data from that application comes back and is sent through the outbound channel.  Everything works perfectly as long as the connections are maintained.  I have been stumped for a while, and I agree that I wouldn't think this is normal.  My thought is that the executor pool gets clogged up looking for the socket to send and then there are no more executors to deliver to other clients?  I'll run a thread dump and post if that will be helpful.  Thanks!!

Comment: @GaryRussell here is a thread dump during lag where no clients are receiving messages http://textuploader.com/d4iwr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not adding up; `threadPoolTaskExecutor-9` is blocked trying to send data to the socket; the connection object is locked...

```
- locked <0x0000000746902810> (a org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection)
```

9 other threads are waiting to acquire that lock (`send()` is `synchronized`), so it appears you are attempting to write multiple messages to the same socket concurrently.

So it's not a problem with sending to other sockets, its a problem sending to that one socket (presumably because its buffers are full).

**EDIT**

Here's one way to perform all outbound sends on a single thread per socket...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46917862Application {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So46917862Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46917862Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1234);
            socket.getOutputStream().write("foo\r\n".getBytes());
            socket.getOutputStream().write("bar\r\n".getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
            socket.close();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(server());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inbound());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inbound() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inbound")
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler asyncResponder() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor exec = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        return m ->
            exec.execute(() -> {
                LOGGER.info("Initiating on this thread");
                toTcp().send(new GenericMessage<>("FOO", m.getHeaders()));
            });
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory server() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outbound")
    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler handler() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler handler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(server());
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel toTcp() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outbound() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleThreadPerConnection sender() {
        return new SingleThreadPerConnection(outbound());
    }

    public static class SingleThreadPerConnection implements ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionCloseEvent> {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingleThreadPerConnection.class);

        private final Map<String, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor> executors = new HashMap<>();

        private final MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

        public SingleThreadPerConnection(MessageChannel channel) {
            this.messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(channel);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
            this.executors.remove(event.getConnectionId()).shutdown();
            LOGGER.info("Removed executor for " + event.getConnectionId());
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
        public void sendToThread(final Message<?> message) {
            executorFor((String) message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID))
                .execute(() -> {
                    LOGGER.info("Sending on this thread");
                    this.messagingTemplate.send(message);
                });
        }

        private synchronized TaskExecutor executorFor(String connectionId) {
            Assert.state(connectionId != null, "No connection id header present");
            if (this.executors.get(connectionId) == null) {
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
                exec.setThreadNamePrefix(connectionId + "-exec-");
                exec.initialize();
                this.executors.put(connectionId, exec);
            }
            return this.executors.get(connectionId);
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

```
2017-10-25 09:37:16.250  INFO 54983 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] com.example.So46917862Application        
: Initiating on this thread
2017-10-25 09:37:16.250  INFO 54983 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] com.example.So46917862Application        
: Initiating on this thread
2017-10-25 09:37:16.253  INFO 54983 --- [20b926b7-exec-1] 862Application$SingleThreadPerConnection 
: Sending on this thread
2017-10-25 09:37:16.253  INFO 54983 --- [20b926b7-exec-1] 862Application$SingleThreadPerConnection 
: Sending on this thread
```

Comment: That sounds right to me.  So, is there something that I'm missing that will queue up the messages to each socket and not clog all the threads?  Or is there a different channel adapter I should be using?  Thanks for looking into this for me!

Comment: Interesting. I need to give it some thought. Perhaps some kind of specialized task executor. It will probably be tomorrow though.

Comment: You, sir, are a giant among developers.

Comment: Confirmed that this solution works.  My test was to connect a couple of telnet clients to the application, and they are all set to receive async messages through the outbound channel.  Once the data starts flowing I would set the network to one of the clients to 100% packet loss, and all the clients would stop receiving messages.  After re-configuring my code with your solution the other clients continue to receive messages.  Thanks so much for your help!!